# Driver crash creating vertex buffer

Tags: c++, driver, direct3d

I am starting working on my first D3D11 "framework" but I get a driver crash (in nvwgf2um.dll) when creating a buffer. I have latest NVIDIA driver

```
ID3D11Buffer* CreateVertexBufferFromGeometry(Mesh& mesh) const{

  [cut unrelated stuff]

    ID3D11Buffer* buffer;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(float) * mesh.NumberOfFloatsPerVertex * mesh.vertexData.size();
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
    InitData.pSysMem = mesh.vertexData.data();          
    RenderDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &buffer);

    return buffer;
}
```

I have Debug layer on and nothing pops, the HRESULT is pointless since the app crashes inside CreateBuffer (does not return) just get this crash in debug and release mode.

What can it be? How can I go on to get more info?

The obj I am trying to read is not ill-formed (it read fine with any viewer).

Thanks

EDIT: RenderDevice is a wrapper around ID3D11Device , it is NOT null and it works in creating other things fine.
EDIT2: Got problem with warp as well

Comment: What is in RenderDevice pointer then?

Comment: Sorry, it is a ID3D11Device

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the vertex data size is correct in `bd.ByteWidth`? Eg. Should you actually be multiplying by the number of floats per vert? If not, it may cause the driver to read potentially invalid system memory. I would try not using the initialization data, just to verify.